# How do I pass the HTTP username from Apache to Mongrel/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, apache2, mongrel

**The goal:** running a Rails application on Mongrels, allowing access through Apache after doing basic HTTP Authentication

**The problem:** reading the supplied username from within Rails

Apache:

```
<Proxy balancer://mongrel_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4001
    # ...

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "<realm>"
    AuthUserFile "<users-file>"
    AuthGroupFile "<groups-file>"
    Require group <group>

    Satisfy Any
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
# ...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://mongrel_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

That works just fine, Apache forces the user to authenticate and forwards to Rails if successful. I omitted a few lines for handling static files and such, and triggering authentication for them as well.

The environment variables from Rails' perspective contain the usual entries and additionally `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. I was unable to pass custom environment variables by adding them to the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ... [P,QSA,L,E=foo:bar]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`RequestHeader`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive to put `REMOTE_USER` in an HTTP header. This seems to have worked for the folks in [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/83067):

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e
```